# Insufficient scope when attempting to get Docker Hub catalog

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm attempting to get a catalog listing for Docker hub, but so far I'm just getting an error in response. My understanding is I'd need to pass a bearer token with the catalog request, so I start by getting that token with the related scope:

```
curl -u "username:password "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=registry:catalog:*"
```

(this is using username/password from my Docker Hub account)

I then pass the returned token to the registry:

```
curl -vL -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6I(...)" https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/_catalog
```

In response to that request, I'm getting:

```
*   Trying 54.86.130.73...
* Connected to registry-1.docker.io (54.86.130.73) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.docker.io
* Server certificate: RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> GET /v2/_catalog HTTP/1.1
> Host: registry-1.docker.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6I(...)
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
< Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="registry:catalog:*",error="insufficient_scope"
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="registry:catalog:*",error="insufficient_scope"
< Date: Fri, 06 May 2016 23:00:08 GMT
Date: Fri, 06 May 2016 23:00:08 GMT
< Content-Length: 134
Content-Length: 134
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
<
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":[{"Type":"registry","Name":"catalog","Action":"*"}]}]}
```

...which seems to be asking me to go back and get authorized with the URL I entered above.

Should this be possible? If so, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on all URLs except /v2/ itself :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same problem, raised this with docker support and got the following answer,
"The catalog endpoint does not work against Docker Hub because that endpoint actually lists all the repositories on a Registry, and we disabled it as it would list all repositories on Docker Hub."

Comment: Fine, Docker. More than one way to skin the cat. :) Thanks for posting the official response, @Rosmi

Answer (score 2):

If you want repository information for a username or organization, an alternative is to use V1 api. The problem with this is you need to make multiple calls based on the number of repos available.

The following command will give the repos available for a given username :

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Basic <encripted username:password>" -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "https://index.docker.io/v1/search?q=<username>&n=100"
```

Here q is the query and n is the number of items to be returned in each page.

Another call can be made based on what data you need by passing repo as a parameter.